AEM clientlib-generator 'DOMNodeInserted' mutation event
I use the clientlib-generator to get my react-app AEM ready.
Since Chrome-Version 127.0.6533.100 the DOMNodeInserted listener is deprecated.
The project folders are not visible in the chrome sources and the app doesn't get rendered. The only error-message that appears in chrome is:
[Deprecation] Listener added for a 'DOMNodeInserted' mutation event. Support for this event type has been removed, and this event will no longer be fired.

The clientlib.min.js file uses the listener:
 document.body.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", (function() {
   return x(t)
 }

Could this be the reason why the folder of the static files are not in the chrome sources and can I replace the listener with a observer instead and what generates the clientlib.min.js file?
